# how use importmulti with import multiple accounts

Tags: import

i'm use:

```
importmulti '[{ "scriptPubKey": { "address": ["3M5egggggggggggttttttttttttttttKEDy","18nbE6bEyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyBiu","1Faew4y2j2TJDGFyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy2W"] }, "timestamp":"now", "keys": [ "Kwngf5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMftBh92c","5KWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxu7KXDLjnmgDDtNepR","L4fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxU7s2C4jpQC3cF" ], "redeemscript": ["00144yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyc3c9f59ab"]}]'
```

return error
help m pls

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Each outer `{...}` is for one individual thing being imported. Importing multiple addresses and their keys is not done by making `address` an array, but rather by having the top level array contain multiple items. Additionally, `redeemScript` is not an array either.

Your command should look something like:

```
importmulti '[{ "scriptPubKey": { "address":"3M5egggggggggggttttttttttttttttKEDy"}, "timestamp": "now", "keys": ["Kwngf5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMftBh92c"], "redeemscript": "00144yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyc3c9f59ab"},{ "scriptPubKey": { "address":"18nbE6bEyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyBiu"}, "timestamp": "now", "keys": ["5KWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxu7KXDLjnmgDDtNepR"]},{ "scriptPubKey": { "address":"1Faew4y2j2TJDGFyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy2W"}, "timestamp": "now", "keys": ["L4fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxU7s2C4jpQC3cF"]}]'
```